# LINQ Distinct with EqualityComparer<T>.Default: IEquatable<T> implementation ignored?

Tags: c#, linq, iequatable

I have a class `Foo` with two fields where the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` methods have been overridden:

```
public class Foo
{
    private readonly int _x;
    private readonly int _y;

    public Foo(int x, int y) { _x = x; _y = y; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj) {
        Foo other = obj as Foo;
        return other != null && _y == other._y;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() { return _y; }
}
```

If I create an array of `Foo`:s and count the number of `Distinct` values of this array:

```
var array = new[] { new Foo(1, 1), new Foo(1, 2), new Foo(2, 2), new Foo(3, 2) };
Console.WriteLine(array.Distinct().Count());
```

The number of distinct values is recognized as:

```
2
```

If I now make my class `Foo` implement `IEquatable<Foo>` using the following implementation:

```
public bool Equals(Foo other) { return _y == other._y; }
```

The number of distinct values is still:

```
2
```

But if I change the implementation to this:

```
public bool Equals(Foo other) { return _x == other._x; }
```

The computed number of distinct `Foo`:s is neither 3 (i.e. the number of distinct `_x`) nor 2 (number of distinct `_y`), but:

```
4
```

And if I comment out the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overrides but keep the `IEquatable<Foo>` implementation, the answer is also `4`.

According to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436.aspx), this `Distinct` overload should use the static property [EqualityComparer.Default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) to define the equality comparison, and:

```
The Default property checks whether type T implements the System.IEquatable<T>
interface and, if so, returns an EqualityComparer<T> that uses that 
implementation. Otherwise, it returns an EqualityComparer<T> that uses the 
overrides of Object.Equals and Object.GetHashCode provided by T.
```

But looking at the experiment above, this statement does not seem to hold. At best, the `IEquatable<Foo>` implementation supports the already provided `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overrides, and at worst it completely corrupts the equality comparison.

My questions:

- Why does the independent implementation of `IEquatable<T>` corrupt the equality comparison?
- Can it play a role independent of the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overrides?
- If not, why does `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` look for this implementation first?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `GetHashCode` method *only* depends on `y`. That means if your `Equals` method *doesn't* depend on `y`, you've broken the contract of equality... they're inconsistent.

`Distinct()` is going to expect that equal elements have the same hash code. In your case, the only equal elements by `x` value have *different* hash codes, therefore `Equals` won't even get called.

From the docs of `IEquatable<T>.Equals`:

> If you implement `Equals`, you should also override the base class implementations of `Object.Equals(Object)` and `GetHashCode` so that their behavior is consistent with that of the `IEquatable<T>.Equals` method.

Your implementation of `Equals(Foo)` isn't consistent with *either* `Equals(object)` *or* `GetHashCode`.

`EqualityComparer<T>.Default` will still delegate to your `GetHashCode` method - it will just use your `Equals(T)` method in preference to your `Equals(object)` method.

So to answer your questions in order:

> - Why does the independent implementation of `IEquatable<T>` corrupt the equality comparison?

Because you've introduced an inconsistent implementation. It's not *meant* to be independent in terms of behaviour. It's just meant to be more efficient by avoiding a type check (and boxing, for value types).

> - Can it play a role independent of the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` overrides?

It should be consistent with `Equals(object)` for the sake of sanity, and it *must* be consistent with `GetHashCode` for the sake of correctness.

> If not, why does `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` look for this implementation first?

To avoid runtime type checking and boxing/unboxing, primarily.

Comment: Many thanks, Jon, very informative answer. I realize I should have read the `IEquatable<T>.Equals` documentation more thoroughly. Good point about type checking, it is obvious *now* that this is the primary benefit :-)